# How does youtube autoplay video with music when we land to some channel's homepage

Tags: html, html5-video

After chrome version [66](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/) autoplay of video with music was not allowed and if we want to autoplay any video we need to keep the video muted but currently when I was going through some youtube channel page and there when I land on the page the video would autoplay with the music and they are also using video API of HTML only when I inspected that player so how is youtube able to autoplay their video with audio. Any ideas ?

For reference if you go to this youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA) the video would autoplay with voice.

Any idea how this is happening ? Curious to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Music is not allowed to autoplay and even if it does it has to be muted, yes.... But, I don't think the same applies for embeds, I believe, youtube bypasses this by embedding the video onto the channel page, I may be wrong.

Comment: If you inspect the player that is playing the video it is using HTML5 video API and not embeding it

Comment: ok idk then, sorry